# Injecting Session with StructureMap in ASP .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, inversion-of-control, structuremap, structuremap3

I am trying to inject ASP .Net MVC Session into a Controller by providing in interface for it using StructureMap. But StructureMap complaints while trying to do this as `HttpContext.Current` is not initialized at the time of registry initialization. I am sure there is a way around it I have yet to find. Please point me into the right direction.

Here is my code for more information:

**DefaultRegistry.cs:**

```
using System.Web;
using Company.O365Web.Infrastructure;
using StructureMap.Configuration.DSL;
using StructureMap.Graph;

namespace Company.O365Web.DependencyResolution
{
    public class DefaultRegistry : Registry
    {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

        public DefaultRegistry()
        {
            Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
            });

            For<ISessionState>()
                .Singleton()
                .Use(new SessionStateProvider(new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session)));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you would be better off building your app to be sessionless

Comment: Which event within your `global.asax.cs` are you setting up your StructureMap configuration?

Comment: Joe's question points to the right direction as the context is not available in all global.asax events